# sum of poisson?

Tags: self-study

we hav $X_1, X_2,...X_{100}$ i.i.d. Poisson with an expected value of one. We need to find an approximation to the probability that the sum is bigger than 85. The correct answer is 0.93319.

So i tried this: I know that the sum of Poisson is a Poisson(100) but the problem is that you have to solve this problem with tables, so i thought that maybe you can use the central limit theorem so i did this: $Z=(85-100)=15$

Comment: Divide (85 - 100) by the standard deviation of the Poisson(100) random variable.

Comment: but still is not the answer, i need that Z to be 1.5, but thank you :)

Comment: What is the standard deviation of a Poisson(100) random variable?

Answer (score 0):

You have a series of $n$ random variables $X_{i}$ where:

$$X_{i}\sim POI(\lambda)$$

Define:

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\sim POI(n\lambda)$$

You want to know:

$$\text{Pr}(S>a)$$

Recall that, for sufficient $n$:

$$S\overset{d}{\to}N(n\lambda,n\lambda)$$

Thus, you need:

$$\text{Pr}\big(N(n\lambda,n\lambda)>a\big)$$

where $n=100$, $\lambda=1$ and $a=85$.